# When should I return a Json-schema to prevent out-of-band transfer of knowledge to REST API client?

Tags: rest, jsonschema, hateoas

In PoC stage to develop a HATEOAS REST API. Zeroed in on [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) for everything schema. I am expecting clients to use this schema to smartly create forms on the fly to create new resources. Just not sure when to return it?

Possible options could be:

1. return it as a link to just another relationship under _schema (like _self)
2. return it on OPTIONS (not convinced though as OPTIONS is not cacheable and supposed to be used only for proxies and cors type of discoveries)
3. return full schema of resource whenever it is anticipated that user may create a new resource (but it may increase the payload and not every time user may want to create)
4. return it if the GET request is coming with a custom header looking for schema.
5. any other smart option that you can come up with :)

Comment: the first option is the most REST-compliant imho.

Comment: Agreed. It is actually the formal way proposed by json-schema. The relationship type in this case is going to be "describedBy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Schema documentation includes two recommendations for correlating documents with schemas.

The first and most popular is to use the `profile` `Content-Type` header attribute.

```
Content-Type: application/my-media-type+json; profile="http://example.com/my-hyper-schema#"
```

The other recommendation (that I have never actually seen anyone use) is a `Link` header with `rel=describedBy`.

```
Link: <http://example.com/my-hyper-schema#>; rel="describedBy"
```

Reference: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor33

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going ahead with "describedBy" approach.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a custom header. That's what the `Accept` header is for. The clients should specify the format they want in the `Accept` header. If you're using HATEOAS you should also be defining your own media-types, as that's the only out-of-band information clients will have, but if you're using generic media-types, you can return json-schema for the `application/schema+json` and simple json for `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yours is also a very valid approach. But I can only mark one as official answer. Going ahead with Jason's approach, hence marking it accordingly.